# URI.encode_www_form returning different values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, uri, url-encoding

When I try this code in Heroku (Ruby 1.9.1):
`URI.encode_www_form({:ids => [1,2,3,4]})`
The method simply encodes the array
`=> "ids=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D"`

When I try the same line in my local env (Ruby 1.9.3), the method encodes the array as HTTP query params:
`=> "ids=1&ids=2&ids=3&ids=4"`

The docs say the second answer is correct (1.9.3) but previous versions of the docs do not specify this method.

What could be causing this issue?